# Determining Anaconda XZ Package Content

Tags: python, anaconda, lzma, xz

I'm currently trying to figure out the contents of an [anaconda package called XZ](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/xz).

From my understanding, the package provides binding for [XZ Utils (data compression tool)](https://tukaani.org/xz/).

I'm trying to figure out the components of XZ Utils that exist within the package, whether it only has the liblzma library, or it also has the command-line tools and shell scripts. Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you very much for taking your time :)

## Methods Tried

I tried looking at the XZ package json file from the conda-meta folder of the environment. I believe that the conda-meta folder holds meta data for each package installed.

The contents of the json file is as below.

```
{
  "build": "h62dcd97_0",
  "build_number": 0,
  "channel": "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64",
  "constrains": [],
  "depends": [
    "vc >=14.1,<15.0a0",
    "vs2015_runtime >=14.16.27012,<15.0a0"
  ],
  "extracted_package_dir": "C:\\Users\\PC-2001-044\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\xz-5.2.5-h62dcd97_0",
  "features": "",
  "files": [
    "Library/bin/liblzma.dll",
    "Library/bin/lzmainfo.exe",
    "Library/bin/unxz.exe",
    "Library/bin/xz.exe",
    "Library/bin/xz_static.exe",
    "Library/include/lzma.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/base.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/bcj.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/block.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/check.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/container.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/delta.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/filter.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/hardware.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/index.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/index_hash.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/lzma12.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/stream_flags.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/version.h",
    "Library/include/lzma/vli.h",
    "Library/lib/liblzma.lib",
    "Library/lib/liblzma_static.lib"
  ],
  "fn": "xz-5.2.5-h62dcd97_0.conda",
  "legacy_bz2_md5": "396bea25a71fe01ac1b4e06805fc9c21",
  "license": "LGPL-2.1 and GPL-2.0",
  "link": {
    "source": "C:\\Users\\PC-2001-044\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\xz-5.2.5-h62dcd97_0",
    "type": 1
  },
  "md5": "31fb0218c036a3afd2e0fa7f5081606d",
  "name": "xz",
  "package_tarball_full_path": "C:\\Users\\PC-2001-044\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\xz-5.2.5-h62dcd97_0",
  "paths_data": {
    "paths": [
      {
        "_path": "Library/bin/liblzma.dll",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "fe7f795dbcd8a5e697abac01f3ce1f9a97fc9eab363adf60cb150bfc24b64c22",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "fe7f795dbcd8a5e697abac01f3ce1f9a97fc9eab363adf60cb150bfc24b64c22",
        "size_in_bytes": 154624
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/bin/lzmainfo.exe",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "1349ca1374597fe134101747ebb9c9474ed836ff858a5ac0a0e0d076253f9b9a",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "1349ca1374597fe134101747ebb9c9474ed836ff858a5ac0a0e0d076253f9b9a",
        "size_in_bytes": 18944
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/bin/unxz.exe",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "9b3240728b422d4b9e0303d071613533b108ed3b15b1353a48aaacc671544806",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "9b3240728b422d4b9e0303d071613533b108ed3b15b1353a48aaacc671544806",
        "size_in_bytes": 20480
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/bin/xz.exe",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "ec1a951bfd1bed6f8cd54a708eaf2680dd9141beaf70e603205ca155b9e91f72",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "ec1a951bfd1bed6f8cd54a708eaf2680dd9141beaf70e603205ca155b9e91f72",
        "size_in_bytes": 66560
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/bin/xz_static.exe",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "751edc488e54990ef1b616aa13c6763db72e8675ef5f90a084bb39dd9bdeeb7c",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "751edc488e54990ef1b616aa13c6763db72e8675ef5f90a084bb39dd9bdeeb7c",
        "size_in_bytes": 195072
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "322a2137797ba67d4381dd2ebc045bf0280ac052b504e83c20464ce3f33ff355",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "322a2137797ba67d4381dd2ebc045bf0280ac052b504e83c20464ce3f33ff355",
        "size_in_bytes": 9866
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/base.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "b49a0688b71b84bce13e80af2a505bbc98f24f04302ceb6a6c5b8d6840a5a971",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "b49a0688b71b84bce13e80af2a505bbc98f24f04302ceb6a6c5b8d6840a5a971",
        "size_in_bytes": 24858
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/bcj.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "485ee1ac185747b6e5324094aa462af194ba3a22a0206314e25f70423045e43d",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "485ee1ac185747b6e5324094aa462af194ba3a22a0206314e25f70423045e43d",
        "size_in_bytes": 2630
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/block.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "6f6935c23c5e34bd0ff9e31998b130f48e54f4794858c0a79cd3dfb8197e660c",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "6f6935c23c5e34bd0ff9e31998b130f48e54f4794858c0a79cd3dfb8197e660c",
        "size_in_bytes": 22107
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/check.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "79ef75b06fe389ccbc47ebeea1bb704157a58fe9710ddfbac8a62035359f9ae1",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "79ef75b06fe389ccbc47ebeea1bb704157a58fe9710ddfbac8a62035359f9ae1",
        "size_in_bytes": 4255
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/container.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "13fbba65515bed9d108e97cba3227604291545290fec3f11d9f5babcc6811404",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "13fbba65515bed9d108e97cba3227604291545290fec3f11d9f5babcc6811404",
        "size_in_bytes": 24844
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/delta.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "db9db049ab07363921bf19320174afbab16a1b4d401f797a5b2232dcb89b9d64",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "db9db049ab07363921bf19320174afbab16a1b4d401f797a5b2232dcb89b9d64",
        "size_in_bytes": 1865
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/filter.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "0c30f1e1271e4bd06e07934b31b76edddbb7d8616e2b8043b36771ade8eb294b",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "0c30f1e1271e4bd06e07934b31b76edddbb7d8616e2b8043b36771ade8eb294b",
        "size_in_bytes": 16520
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/hardware.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "7c9c7fdd29650a730e59281ea38e3826d94b518fa7e23573b9303ac8f3421083",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "7c9c7fdd29650a730e59281ea38e3826d94b518fa7e23573b9303ac8f3421083",
        "size_in_bytes": 2604
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/index.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "9eb7451f4d8de7d51a17585b7a86c3b4eb02d00d7e7fc1c390255e34231f3516",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "9eb7451f4d8de7d51a17585b7a86c3b4eb02d00d7e7fc1c390255e34231f3516",
        "size_in_bytes": 23491
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/index_hash.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "0840c2ae8dedc05a7ffe1597ead131532a8dc03521728d1d38e55da0fa769831",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "0840c2ae8dedc05a7ffe1597ead131532a8dc03521728d1d38e55da0fa769831",
        "size_in_bytes": 3914
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/lzma12.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "caf8948b9306d508026cc3bbadea579eb8e75a24c444fdbe9986a4cc01a7b362",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "caf8948b9306d508026cc3bbadea579eb8e75a24c444fdbe9986a4cc01a7b362",
        "size_in_bytes": 14744
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/stream_flags.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "beba70fa9d83dc6a7fcfae9b1f8d07b3b5acbbdc789f008e63da4206e2434acc",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "beba70fa9d83dc6a7fcfae9b1f8d07b3b5acbbdc789f008e63da4206e2434acc",
        "size_in_bytes": 8253
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/version.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "a334c2e4d0f31e023f78e8582823166e342dfe3f661e28e0c549277aa2843592",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "a334c2e4d0f31e023f78e8582823166e342dfe3f661e28e0c549277aa2843592",
        "size_in_bytes": 3497
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/include/lzma/vli.h",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "501ba06a4c33a45d83d830975643bdb646936e9e47fd07124c843453cf9a8776",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "501ba06a4c33a45d83d830975643bdb646936e9e47fd07124c843453cf9a8776",
        "size_in_bytes": 6546
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/lib/liblzma.lib",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "95089afbc9770811fb9e937a1fd2f66c6215b26904c68adaad0ec382a02b193f",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "95089afbc9770811fb9e937a1fd2f66c6215b26904c68adaad0ec382a02b193f",
        "size_in_bytes": 23762
      },
      {
        "_path": "Library/lib/liblzma_static.lib",
        "path_type": "hardlink",
        "sha256": "bafec57c200c828af0483b419e6b2a9ba5e86647fc6db21404c3d6039f7f3824",
        "sha256_in_prefix": "bafec57c200c828af0483b419e6b2a9ba5e86647fc6db21404c3d6039f7f3824",
        "size_in_bytes": 448374
      }
    ],
    "paths_version": 1
  },
  "requested_spec": "None",
  "sha256": "09283b85fe4fe6621830bbcc668808fbd92930c9e5ee650509524b24ccdee477",
  "size": 249708,
  "subdir": "win-64",
  "timestamp": 1587011860942,
  "track_features": "",
  "url": "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/xz-5.2.5-h62dcd97_0.conda",
  "version": "5.2.5"
}
```

From the "files" section, I believe it tells what files the package provides. It does state that it has the liblzma library. It also shows "xz.exe", which I assume might be the command-line tool, but I couldn't guarantee it.

## Motivation

For context, I'm actually trying to avoid using gpl licensed software. From the documentation, it states that [different licenses are applied to different parts of xz utils](https://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=COPYING). After researching a little bit, python actually already has a [buildin binding to liblzma](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html), so I was kinda wondering what does this package provides.

Comment: Hi! Why do you want to find out the package contents? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi @darthbith ! I'm actually trying to avoid using gpl licensed software. From the documentation, it states that [different licenses are applied to different parts of xz utils](https://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=COPYING). After researching a little bit, python actually already has a [buildin binding to liblzma](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html), so I was kinda wondering what does this package provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an [issue on XZ conda-forge package's repo](https://github.com/conda-forge/xz-feedstock/issues/26) that corresponds to my question.

I posted more on this on [my question on the open source stack exchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/12534/25528).

In short, the component of "scripts to grep, diff and view compressed file" does not exists in the package.

The question still remains for the command-line components, however.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `files:` section lists the files that will install into the environment. The ones under `bin/` will be executable programs, `lib/` the shared libraries, and `include/` the header files for compiling against it.